# Formula of 1 form in R3

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I want to solve the following problem: Given $d ◦ d = 0$, d acting on $0$-form and $1$-form, I want to show that both $1$-form and $0$-form yield $0$.

I finished in the case of $0$-form using that the following equation; 
$df =(∂f/∂x)dx + (∂f/∂y)dy + (∂f/∂z)dz$.

But I have no clue whatsoever in the case of 1$$-form.

Does 1$$-form looks like $fdx\land dy\land dz$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic 1-form on $\Bbb R^3$ has the form 
$$
\omega = f_1(x, y, z)~dx  + f_2(x, y, z) ~dy + f_3 (x, y, z) ~dz,
$$
where one typically assumes that the $f_i$ are differentiable functions.

Answer (score 1):

One the other properties of $d$ is that it is a derivation. 
Suppose $\omega = f(x,y,z)\,dx$.  Then
\begin{align*}
    d\omega &= df \wedge dx = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz\right)\wedge dx \\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz \wedge dx
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
    d^2 \omega &= d\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \wedge dy \wedge dx
               +d\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) \wedge dz \wedge dx \\
    &= \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y}dx +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\,\partial y}dz\right) \wedge dy \wedge dx
               +\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial z}dx + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\,\partial z}dy + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}dz\right) \wedge dz \wedge dx \\
    &= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\,\partial y}dz\wedge dy \wedge dx
      +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\,\partial z}dy\wedge dz \wedge dx
\end{align*}
If $f$ is $C^2$, then the two partial derivatives above are equal.  Since
\begin{align*}
    dz \wedge dy \wedge dx &= - dx\wedge dy \wedge dz \\
    dy \wedge dz \wedge dx &=   dx\wedge dy \wedge dz
\end{align*}
the two terms sum to zero.